# I've searched many post but can't find my answer

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I've searched for help before posting and read many post on how to turn conditional formatting on/off or disable it within a file.

Is there any way to remove the automatic conditional formatting on all sheets to prevent it from being auto applied to the file and having to turn off or disable.

The spreadsheets I use are used for uploading data into my company's database and can contain certain information only so the toggle on/off is not an option and having to disable the formatting for every file is frustrating.

I'd like to disable the prior month conditional formatting rule from all sheets. Is it possible to permanently disable within Excel's options menu by by clicking File, Options...etc?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [edit] the title of your question to reflect your actual question. This will make it easier for others to find.

Answer (score 1):

To remove conditional formatting on the cells of a **single** sheet, select it and run:

```
Sub Unconditional()
    ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
End Sub
```

If this works for you then modify the code to loop  over all worksheets.

Comment: Please provide data to loop over all worksheets. Thanks so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use this VBA code(Macro) to clear all applied Conditional Formats from the Sheets in Workbook.*

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  For Each TmpSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    TmpSht.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

  Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to disable conditional formatting "prior" to opening all workbooks.

Comment: @ginmcbride,, how it's possible,,, !!. Unless the Workbook is not open how could you apply any command? This is the best possible method.